Как добавить данные в столбец со спец символами в названии SQL (EXCEL)
"INSERT INTO [TempTable$] (Ид. случая) VALUES ('1')" 

Мне надо добавить данные в таблицу Excel. Подключаюсь к xlsx как к db. Но в первой строке файла названия колонок содержат спец символы.
Как правильно их экранировать в запросе?
Вариант экранирования [Ид. случая] работает только для пробела (если удалить точку из названия)
"INSERT INTO [TempTable$] ([Ид. случая]) VALUES ('1')" 

получаю ошибку

Invalid bracketing of name '[Ид. случая]'



Уберите лишние теги и добавьте более подробное описание того, что вас интересует. Куда что добавить.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Вроде как точка . подставляется решеткой #. Хотя есть вообще универсальный метод: 1. Найти в Excel таблицу со столбцом где указаны специальные символы. 2. Попробовать полностью загрузить эту таблицу в DataSet\DataTable используя звездочку (*) 3. В отладчике посмотреть как подставляется имя указанного столбца. 4. Скопировать его и далее уже применить его где надо.
